# About use python package called timm by pycharm

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pycharm

### Problem：

I use timm package in pycharm ,code following:

```py
import timm

model = timm.create_model('swin_base_patch4_window7_224.ms_in22k_ft_in1k', pretrained=True)
```

When i run this program in pycharm, the error following:

> ...
> urllib3.util.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError: hostname 'huggingface.co' doesn't match either of '*.facebook.com', '*.facebook.net', '*.fbcdn.net', '*.fbsbx.com', '*.m.facebook.com', '*.messenger.com', '*.xx.fbcdn.net', '*.xy.fbcdn.net', '*.xz.fbcdn.net', 'facebook.com', 'messenger.com'
>
> ...
>
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /timm/swin_base_patch4_window7_224.ms_in22k_ft_in1k/resolve/main/model.safetensors (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'huggingface.co' doesn't match either of '*.facebook.com', '*.facebook.net', '*.fbcdn.net', '*.fbsbx.com', '*.m.facebook.com', '*.messenger.com', '*.xx.fbcdn.net', '*.xy.fbcdn.net', '*.xz.fbcdn.net', 'facebook.com', 'messenger.com'")))
> ...
> requests.exceptions.SSLError: (MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /timm/swin_base_patch4_window7_224.ms_in22k_ft_in1k/resolve/main/model.safetensors (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'huggingface.co' doesn't match either of '*.facebook.com', '*.facebook.net', '*.fbcdn.net', '*.fbsbx.com', '*.m.facebook.com', '*.messenger.com', '*.xx.fbcdn.net', '*.xy.fbcdn.net', '*.xz.fbcdn.net', 'facebook.com', 'messenger.com'")))'), '(Request ID: 130e0277-d69a-4796-a53c-45d59ffc8d51)')

I run this program in terminal, the Program run successfully.
How can i fix it.